# Access - how to allow edits in the last row but not in previous rows?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the form and in this form I have button which asks me which row I want to duplicate. And it also opens the last row (so the duplicated one) and I want to be able to edit this one row in form, but I didn't allow edits in any other previous rows.

So basically I want to allow edits only in the last, latest row. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the OnCurrent event:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Me.AllowEdits = (Me.CurrentRecord = Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount)

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work, I can still edit the previous rows

Comment: It is tested and works here, so double-check and try again.